# Shadow DOM Insertion Point. Select only Text

Tags: shadow-dom

I didnt find anything how to select just Text for the Insertion Point of the Shadow DOM.

something like:

```
<content select="text"></content>
```

Is there a selector for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to spec:

> The matching criteria for an insertion point is a set of compound
>   selectors [SELECTORS4]. These compound selectors are restricted to
>   contain only these simple selectors:
>
> - A type selector or a universal selector
> - class selector(s)
> - An ID selector
> - attribute selector(s)
> - A negation pseudo-class, :not()

http://www.w3.org/TR/shadow-dom/#satisfying-matching-criteria

There is no text selector.